# C assembly programming

Tags: c, assembly, 64-bit, intel

I got this working everyone thank you!

I have a homework to write an assembly program mulq.s that goes with my C program bigmult.c

The C program is supposed to multiply two unsigned hexadecimal numbers together. I got it started but I think I need a lot of help. This is an introduction to assembly so it's not very long.

Here is the full question:

> You are to write a C program called
>   big_mult.c that multiplies two unsigned integers, x and y, read from
>   the command line. The output is a pair of unsigned integers
>   representing the most significant and least significant 64 bits of the
>   full 128-bit product x * y. The inputs and outputs are to be given in
>   hexadecimal format. Your C program will take care of reading the
>   inputs and printing the output, but it will call a function mull.s to
>   do the actual multiplication. Your C program should use only int or
>   unsigned int variables and should not do any arithmetic. The function
>   defined by mull.s should have the following declaration in C before
>   the procedure main. void mull(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned
>   int* high, unsigned int* low);
>   The least significant 64 bits of the product are to be assigned to
>   low, and the most significant 64 bits of the product are to be
>   assigned to high. Remember to put an appropriate header comment into
>   your assembly file (the ordinary C comment /* ... */ will work for
>   assembly too).
>   One way to approach writing this assembly program is to write a
>   similar program in C, compile it to assembly code using the -S option,
>   and modify the resulting assembly code to do what you need. Your final
>   assembly code should be very short and should contain only one
>   multiplication instruction mull.

I started writing a dummy program to get the unimportant parts of the code at the top and then I'm completely lost on what to do. I have pushq instruction to push %rbp and move the address to %rsp. What am I supposed to do after this?

Any hints would be welcome!

My code so far:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
```

My C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void mull(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int* high, unsigned int* low);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unsigned long long int x, y;
    if(argc != 3)
        printf("Usage: bigmult x1 x2 <where x1 and x2 are hexadecimal integers>\n");
    else {
        sscanf(argv[1], "%x", &x);
        sscanf(argv[2], "%x", &y);
        printf("%x x %x = ", x, y);
        mull(x, y, &x, &y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried following the suggestion given?

Comment: `One way to approach writing this assembly program is to write a similar program in C, compile it to assembly code using the -S option, and modify the resulting assembly code to do what you need.` is a good starting point.

Comment: May I be more forthright? Please **do the suggestion**. Write a C program that handles everything, without any assembler. Then use the output produced by the -S. You will get almost everything that you are struggling with 'for free'.

Comment: I actually tried that and that's how I got the code I have so far. I have no idea what to do next. In the 32 bit version of this program, I would have to build a stack but I don't know how to do this in 64 bit. The professor mentioned the 64 bit is a little easier but I don't know how to even start.

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but I already have my bigmult.c written. I'll edit it in to my code. The only reason I ask this because the -S option gives me back 100s of instructions which I am sure that I don't need. And also, the assembly code is supposed to do the multiplication, and not the c program so I'm kinda confused on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Please post the source of your C program

Comment: I added my C file to the post. I'm also confused on how to actually print the result since mull is a void funtion...So if I use the mull instruction in my assembly code, how will it print the answer back in the command line when the program runs?

Comment: You shouldn't have a `main` in the C code that you will use as starting point for the assembler code.

Comment: No for my starting point, as I mentioned, I used a dummy c program that included a single multiplication line. int z = x * y;

Comment: Make sure you keep the code in two files, one with the main, and the other with mull. Where is the C code for mull?  Write a mull **function** in C, using the declaration given in the question, and have it in a second file. Your instructor is being very helpful.

Comment: Can't I just put the mull function next to my main method? Will that work?

Comment: Ideally, the C mull function will do everything as close as practical to make it easy to make the changes to assembler. Once you have a C mull function, you will have most of the assembler that is need for the assignment. The assembler mulq will be put into the assembler file generated by the -S option. That will be almost the last step, and you have plenty to do before you do that.

Comment: Can't you avoid implicit conversions? Why inputs are **long long int** if you just need an **unsigned int**? Do you need to save few bytes of memory? Do not reuse the same variables as input and output, it'll make your assembly code harder to understand. I agree with **gbulmer** and **pmg**, for your sanity you should strip your pseudo-C mull function from that file! Moreover don't forget to disable compiler **optimizations** (do not compile in debug, release version but without optimizations).

Comment: `mull()` written in C can of course exist in the same file as `main()`. But once you define an assembly version of `mull()` and start to compile your program with it, you will have to remove the C version of `mull()` otherwise you'll have linking errors.

Comment: You _could_ put mull and main into the same file, but then you'd have to work out how to extract just that part which is need for the assembler function. If you put the mull function in the same file as main, you will have to work through hundreds of lines of extra code. If you put it into a separate file, that file contains everything needed. I suggest you try to think through these questions before asking for help. Try thinking about it this way: "My instructor is giving very helpful guidance on how to do this. They have worked very hard to improve the chances that I will succeed."

Comment: If gcc's output with the `-S` option contains too many unnecessary instructions, try adding an optimization option like `-O1` or `-O2` and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm supposed to add my forward declaration of the mull function above my main method. That's what the instructor told us to do. I will edit this post with my mull function in a bit.

Comment: @Alex: to add optimizations? They **could** make his assembly code shorter but less linear and easy to understand.

Comment: What's the command for optimizations? Is it gcc -S -O1 main.c?

Comment: @Adriano: I don't exclude such a possibility.

Comment: I think using web search would help immensely with many little questions such as the command line options. And I'm pretty sure the entire question of writing simple functions in assembly and interfacing them with C(++) code has been answered numerous times elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would love to add my own comment but the !#*&$% stackoverflow rules prohibit me from commenting until I have 28 million cred points (perhaps a bit fewer).

First of all, you want to write your mull() function in C just as simply as possible.  The resulting code will be simpler (MUCH simpler) if you use as inputs two 32-bit integers (probably just 'int', but depends on your platform).  If you do that, judging from your professor's comments, that should boil down to a single multiply instruction that does 32bit*32bit=64bit multiplication.  If you use 64-bit integers as your inputs, there may not be a 64bit*64bit=128bit instruction on your CPU, but even if there is it's overkill for your assignment.  If there isn't, then the compiler will emit a sequence of instructions to perform the 64bit*64bit=128bit multiplication, making it oh-so-much-harder for you to understand what's going on.

When you get your separate C file building to an object file & linking with main()'s object file, what you want to do then is get its disassembly & look for the multiply instruction.  Once you've found it, track backwards to find out where its arguments came from... they may be in registers or perhaps memory locations on the stack, depending on your system's ABI.  Then trace forwards until the function's return to see where the results of the multiplication go when it's returned to the caller.

You will want to duplicate that functionality in your assembly version of mult(), but with this exception:  The C-code compiled version probably includes a good bit of prologue and epilogue instructions that simply aren't needed in a function that's as simple as mult().  But unless the compiler is really really good at optimizing, it won't notice that and the compiled result will be probably eight times as long as it really needs to be.  From your professor's comments, your entire mult() assemly function might even be as short as 2 to 6 instruction total... and depending on your ABI, you may or may not even need to use the stack.  (For x86, you will, but for PowerPC or other RISC machines you wouldn't need to for such a simple function since for many RISC machines, functions with just a few args get all their args passed in registers so they don't need the stack at all.)

So, assuming you DO need to use the stack, your function might look something like this:

```
_mult:
   ...instructions to move parameters from stack locations into registers...
   ...multiply instruction using those registers...
   ...instructions to move the results into the appropriate stack locations
      for return values (or return value registers, depending on your ABI)...
   ...and finally, your processor's "return" instruction
```

...for a total of perhaps 6 instructions maximum.